# How to strobe high power led while maintaining constant current

Tags: led, switching, infrared, led-driver, constant-current

I am trying to make a high power tv-be-gone. For those who don't know, it uses arduino or attiny to run through every IR power code for most tv brands. I have made regular ones that use several 5mm IR leds, however in all of the designs they are just connected to transistors and don't limit current, since the pulses are so fast. These designs run off of 3v-5v. My question is, how can I use a constant current source with a 10W led with the device? My concern is that a cc source will not be able to adjust fast enough when pulsing the IR codes. Do I even need a cc source when switching this fast? Also, I am curious as to why the small tv-be-gones don't need current limiting such as resistors for the IR leds. They have a forward voltage of 1.2v, and are being powered directly by 3v-5v. In this case, what determines the current through the led when no resistor/cc source is connected? Why do the 5mm leds not burn out?

Comment: Can you show an example schematic?

Comment: Are they powered by coin cells, by any chance? Coin cells are known to be weak enough that you can power an LED directly off one and the cell's own internal resistance is enough.

Comment: Using a CC source to control a high power LED is a good idea.  Most voltage regulator chips that have external feedback can be used as a CC source, and a lot of them have an enable input. So you can turn them off/on pretty fast.  But I guess to know for sure you'll need to know the switching frequency. 20kHz, 40kHz?

Comment: Aaron, the ir codes frequency is ~38kHz. user253751, they are alkaline batteries, however I have used lipos and the leds don't burn out.

Comment: Amazon has pages of high power constant current drivers with TTL modulation, some advertising >100 KHz.

Comment: FYI, put an "@" symbol in front of the name to tag someone, and the system will notify that user of the comment.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, I didn’t know that. I’m just used to reddit where you just reply to comments lol

Comment: Are there even 10 W IR LEDs available? I mean high-power IR LEDs such as the Osram SFH 4545 'just' have a maximum power consumption rating of 180 mW. It can be driven by max 1A - but just at low duty cycles. If there is a 10 W IR LED one should probably look into eye safety risks.